# Is it possible to access google drive files of user who haven't enabled drive sdk

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am creating a client application for google drive using java
i have read https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java and have started up with gogle drive sdk.
but my intention is to let user(who will use my client app) upload/download files from "their" google drive account.
is it possible if they have not enabled drive sdk from google api console.
(user cant do it as they are no developers and they dont know about it)
or is there any way that i can enable the sdk for their accnt (through java code)?

Answer (score 0):

Users of your application do not need to enable Drive SDK in the API console. Only the application needs to have it enabled.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. and where could I find info to install my application to the users account..?